Limited video bandwidth with Nvidia
I am running latest version of fedora with nvidia proprietary drivers and I use the NVidia RTX 3080. When I use 3 monitors, if I set the refresh rate low enough on my biggest monitor it works fine but if I set it to max it causes all 3 displays to start flickering and lagging or to go black. However if I plug in just 2 of the monitors I can set the refresh rate to max. I can only assume this is an issue with total video throughput on Linux, and I know it’s not a hardware issue as everything works on Windows. Any idea how to fix it?

Ask here: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/c/gpu-graphics/linux/148
